# NSNumber assignment issues. Wrong number being assigned

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm receiving data in JSON from an API and after converting the data into custom class I'm attempting to write certain properties into a core-data db.

My code is:

```
NSLog(@"topPost: %@; post(in): %@", topPostsEntity.totalAgainst,post.totalAgainst);
topPostsEntity.totalAgainst = post.totalAgainst;
NSLog(@"topPost: %@; post(in): %@", topPostsEntity.totalAgainst,post.totalAgainst);
```

topPostEntity is a Core-Data entity.
topPostEntity.totalAgainst is defined as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * totalAgainst;
```

Nothing special in the getter:

```
- (NSNumber *)totalAgainst
{
    if (!_totalAgainst) _totalAgainst = [[NSNumber alloc]init];
    return _totalAgainst;
}
```

post.totalAgainst is also defined as an NSNumber as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *totalAgainst;
```

To my shock this is what the log reads:

```
2013-11-02 00:42:42.476 kello[6260:70b] topPost: 0; post(in): 40000
2013-11-02 00:42:42.476 kello[6260:70b] topPost: -25536; post(in): 40000
```

How does assigning 40000 to topPostEntity.totalAgainst make it store -25536?

Comment: That's the getter, not the setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

I had set the core-data entity to Integer 16. I changed this to Integer 64 and that resolved the problem. I'm not sure how anyone's going to find this q to help their problem, but if so - cheers.